# IE 8 bug regarding overflow hidden in the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make a rich text editor with the background set on iframes body.
The background is repeated in y axis and when the user types in the string without any spaces the horizontal scroll appears and the background is moved to the left. I fixed it with overflow-x:hidden in all browsers except IE 8 where the behaviour is the same as with overflow:auto but without horisontal scrollbar appearing after the text gets beyond the intended width.

I want IE 8 to clip the excess content which can not be wrapped the same as with other browsers.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 3):

been a year. You might have already found your answer, but anyway,

Yes there is a problem with IE - iframe - and Scrolling

IE doesnt render/accept style="overflow: hidden".

To remove scrolling, set attrib of iframe: *scrolling="no"*

However, I don't know how to set/unset scrolling for only one of the axes..

All the best. Do let us know if you find anything further.

Cheers!
Kris

Comment: If you add scrolling="no" it won't validate. I'm still looking for a solution though XD